# Nested retained FragmentTabHost doesn't attach tabs to new Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment-tab-host

I have been playing around with FragmentTabHost from Android v4 Support library for a while and came upon a serious issue that I couldn't resolve. My target requirements were as follows.

1) `Fragment` that would include tabs built also from `Fragments` which include nested `Fragments` as well, with hierarchy like this:

- `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` (HostFragment)

  - `android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost` (TabHost)

    - `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` (Tab1Fragment)

      - `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` (Tab1Fragment1)
      - `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` (Tab1Fragment2)
      - `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` (Tab1Fragment3)
    - `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` (Tab2Fragment)

      - `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` (Tab2Fragment1)
      - `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` (Tab2Fragment2)

`HostFragment + TabHost` setup was done according to what says in the documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTabHost.html).

2) Upon screen rotation retain status of `HostFragment` as recreation of this setup is a resources consuming operation and besides layout order nothing changes on this screen so no extra work would be needed to just display the screen. Just return a different `layout` in `onCreateView` callback of `Tab1` and `Tab2` and reattach existing fragments to the same id's.

To accomplish that one would think that just setting `HostFragment.setRetainInstance(true)` would do the work and, partially, it does. Nothing was getting recreated, tabs were preserved as they should, all worked fine. Now let's get to the point.

**The Problem**

The big problem came up a bit later. It appears that `Tab1Fragment1` (and all other `TabXFragmentY` for that matter) are not attached to new `Activity` that is created upon rotation. They are only attached on the first run of the `Activity` and then nothing is being done when user rotates the screen.

**The Consequences**

This causes two big issues for me (might be there are more):

1. Initial `Activity` is leaked because all the `Fragments` in the `TabHost` are attached to it for no reason at all.
2. When you call `getActivity()` on any of the `TabXFragmentY` you will get the **old** `Activity` and the dreadful "cannot perform operation after onSavedInstance" exception.

This leads to serious issues when you want something from the parent Activity. Also, it doesn't happen when setting `HostFragment.setRetainInstance(false)` everything get's recreated and works fine.

**The Question**

Is it an issue that I am only seeing?  I couldn't find anything on the topic and I have reviewed my code a hundred times.

I have also tried changing `com.example.android.supportv4.app.FragmentTabsFragmentSupport` from the v4 examples, I did set it to retain it's instance and added a logging information in one of its nested fragments on every `onAttach` call to verify and I can see there still the same issue. I am puzzled. Help.

Comment: The problem is `HostFragment.setRetainInstance(true)`. `setRetainInstance(true)` should simply not be used for `Fragments` that handle views. You should be restoring state using `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle)`.

Comment: But what you are saying is something from your experience or something mentioned in the docs that I have missed out about Fragments?

Comment: Its not directly stated in the docs, but retained Fragments should primarily be used just to maintain a state object and/or process. If you use them to maintain views, you will run into the issues above due to the differing life cycle. If you keep it this way, you can get the proper reference to the parent Activity only after onActivityCreated.

Comment: But over here I am not storing any views directly, on every rotation onCreateView() for the child fragments is getting called so view is rebuilt, only its state is preserved within model objects.

Comment: Can you try moving the child fragment transactions into `onActivityCreated`?

Comment: Paul I could do it for the children of `Tab1Fragment` and `Tab2Fragment` fragments but I won't be able to reuse child fragments (Tab[1,2]FragmentX) because they are still attached to the old Activity (onDetach on TabXFragmentX is not called. I cannot do it for `Tab1Fragment` and `Tab2Fragment` because those are created in the `FragmentTabHost` and managed there. While investigating I have noticed that `onAttach(Activity)` is called only on `HostFragment`and none of its children is getting the callback when `HostFragment` is retained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recently I've been working on a `TabHost` with `Fragment`s and found the same issue. Basically, you need to control which `Fragment`s are being attached/detached, in my case, I do this within the `onTabChanged()` event.

I have a `TabInfo` class where I store the following information for each `Tab`

- The name of the `Fragment` (for identification purposes).
- The `Fragment` to attach.
- The `TabHost.TabSpec` specification, as if you want to remove some tab, there's the info for recreating the rest of them as `TabHost` is a bit tricky for removing tabs.
- The `Bundle` associated (basically, the saved instance prior to a configuration change).

Also, I need to keep track of the `lastTab` and the `newTab` opened as `TabHost` doesn't have a native way of knowing which `TabHost` have been just closed, so I do it declaring a variable class-wide. And this is how I handle it right now, I'll try to add as many comments as I can:

```
@Override
public void onTabChanged(final String tag) {
  // I get the info for the Tab just triggered using its tag
  final TabInfo newTab = mTabInfo.get(tag);

  // If there's actually been a tab change...
  if (lastTab != newTab) {
    // You'll have to make a transaction for replacing the Fragment
    final FragmentTransaction ft = this.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

    // If the last tab actually has a Fragment associated to it
    if ((lastTab != null) && (lastTab.getFragment() != null)) {
      // In my case I've an additional level of complexion, as I have a nested Fragment
      // inside my content Fragment. So I have to remove it first prior to detaching
      // the parent Fragment. This is not needed if you have just one Fragment as content.
      final Fragment loginFrag = (Fragment) lastTab.getFragment().getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(lastTab.getLoginFragId());
      ft.remove(loginFrag);

      // And this is what does the trick: I initially was calling detach() instead of remove()
      // but seems that with some versions there's a problem that makes not apply it,
      // calling remove will actually remove this Fragment
      ft.remove(lastTab.getFragment());
    }

    // You've detached the old Fragment, you have now to attach the new one
    if (newTab != null) {
      if (newTab.getFragment() == null) {
        // Inflate the new content if it's the first time the tab has been fired
        final TabFragmentInflater tabInf = new TabFragmentInflater();
        newTab.setFragment(Fragment.instantiate(this, tabInf.getClass().getName(), newTab.getArgs()));
        ft.add(R.id.realtabcontent, newTab.getFragment(), newTab.getTag());
      }
      else {
        // if not, just attach its fragment
        ft.attach(newTab.getFragment());
      }
    }

    ft.commit();
    this.getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();

    lastTab = newTab;
  }
}
```

**---- EDIT ----**

Answering to your questions:

- I indeed call `newTabSpec()` over the `TabHost`, it's in a separate method I didn't include because I just included the `onTabChanged()` callback. You *have* to create the tabs normally, this `onTabChanged()` method just gets fired when you click on tabs. For the creation, I do something like this:

  ```
  private void initTabHost(final Bundle args) {
    final TabHost th = (TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    th.setup();

    // I have a HashMap called fragMap where as the key I define the tab's name
    // And as the value, I have an Integer which is a unique identifier
    // to know what to inflate when I call the TabFragmentInflater (I will
    // add the code below). You can perfectly add it as an id or a tag also.
    for (final String tablabel : fragMap.keySet()) {
      final TabHost.TabSpec tabSpec = th.get().newTabSpec(tabname).setIndicator(tabname);
      // Here I initialize a TabInfo object for this tab, which will include additional 
      // Handling info: Name of tab, Tab Spec, The unique ID I explained above,
      // the forth argument is irrelevant in your example, and args (saved instance)
      final TabInfo tabInfo = new TabInfo(tabname, tabSpec, fragMap.get(tablabel), R.id.someLayout, args);

      // This is not actually the TabHost's `addTab()` method, I'll call it inside
      // this method (see below)
      MyClass.addTab(this, th, tabSpec, tabInfo);

      // I have to be able to keep tracking of that info
      mTabInfo.put(tabInfo.getTag(), tabInfo);
    }

    // For the tab creation, I force it to start on the first tab
    this.onTabChanged(firstTabNameTag);
    th.setOnTabChangedListener(this);
  }
  ```

The `addTab()` method is very simple, it inflates the object and detaches it if needed.

```
private static void addTab(final MyClass activity, final TabHost tabHost, final TabHost.TabSpec tabSpec, final TabInfo tabInfo) {
  tabSpec.setContent(new TabFactory(activity));    // This is just an empty View
  final String tag = tabSpec.getTag();

  // Here I check if there's already a Fragment for that tab, probably in a 
  // previously saved state. If this happens, we deactivate it, because our
  // former state for that tab is "not shown".
  tabInfo.setFragment(activity.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(tag));
  if ((tabInfo.getFragment() != null) && (!tabInfo.getFragment().isDetached())) {
    final FragmentTransaction ft = activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.detach(tabInfo.getFragment());
    ft.commit();

    activity.getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
  }

  // Actually, there's where I call the "official" `addTab()` from `TabHost`
  tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);
}
```

- So there's just the TabFragmentInflater left. It's just a `Fragment` that inflates the according layout depending on the unique ID I mentioned above, so it's something like this:

  ```
  @Override
  public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container, final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    fragId = getArguments().getInt("fragid");

    if (view != null) {
      ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
      if (parent != null)
        parent.removeView(view);
    }

    try {
      switch (fragId) {
        case 1:         // My first tab...
          final LinearLayout fragLayout = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.myfirsttab_fragment_layout, container, false);

          ...      
          return fragLayout;

        case 2:           // My second tab
          fragLayout = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.mysecondtab_fragment_layout, container, false);

          ...
          return fragLayout;

        ...
      }
    } 
    catch (final InflateException e) { return view; }

    return null;    
  }
  ```

Comment: I have tried applying your solution and have two questions. I am using example as over here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTabHost.html with the second solution for nested fragments. From what I understand you do not use  mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("simple").setIndicator("Simple"), FragmentStackSupport.CountingFragment.class, null); to attach tabs on the initial run? Then how do you set tab indicators? What exactly is the TabFragmentInflater? Please id you could update the response it would be most helpful.

Comment: So from what I see you do not use `android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost` and instead handle the case entirely on your own using the `android.widget.TabHost` component? `android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost` derives from `TabHost` and has some of the handling you mentioned included. The question is about that derivate, not about `TabHost` component, please look at the class hierarchy here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTabHost.html

Comment: I'm indeed using `android.widget.TabHost` but inside an `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` component, the way of handling the `TabHost` is very similar from my approach to what you're looking for and is perfectly extendable, as both uses the same tab functions and work in the same way (`setup()`, `addTab(...)`...)

Comment: So basically your advice is to use of `TabHost`, own management of tabbed `Fragments` and not using `FragmentTabHost` provided by Google for that case?

Comment: No, you can use `FragmentTabHost` the way you're already doing, even it's more recommendable than my approach, what I say is that the code I've posted is compatible with your problem too, you would probably just need to change a few things to adapt it to your code, but it's a valid approach.

Comment: Ok, got it :-) Thanks for your help. Combining information from what Paul said and information you provided I think I have enough information to keep my mind at rest about it. However I think Fragments still need some work from Google side, or at least to document stuff you shouldn't be doing, they are too complicated to manage. Thanks!

Comment: I agree with that, some of those are very poorly documented and it's very difficult to find a real example on how to procceed. But well, that's why StackOverflow is here :-) Hope it helped you, good luck.